# Shorten a long case function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a question about case functions, i have 291 different when this then that, and want to pout it in a array that looks in to the array this gives me the answer.

i want to change 291 lines of a case statement to 1 maybe.

i am trying this example on https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_case using the OrderDetails table

```
SELECT OrderID, Quantity,
CASE WHEN Quantity in (12,10,5) THEN Quantity in (1,2,3)
ELSE null
END AS QuantityText
FROM OrderDetails;
```

i want this to display; if quantity is 12 then show 1 
if quantity is 10 then show 2 
if quantity is 5 then show 3

the output at the moment is 
if quantity is 12 then shows 0
if quantity is 10 then shows 0
if quantity is 5 then shows 0

Comment: That syntax above isn't even valid T-SQL. If you have 291 different variations for your `WHEN` though, sounds like you'd be better off with a lookup table and a `(LEFT) JOIN`

Comment: If you have 291 cases, then it seems to me the correct tool to use is a lookup table where you map the individual values, not a mass of unmaintainable code.

Comment: You tagged this with sql server but the w3schools link is for mysql. And the output you claim you are getting from your code is impossible because in either DBMS this is invalid syntax. It makes no sense.

Comment: @PratikBhavsar knowing what RDBMS that the OP is actually using is really important for helping the them. Every RDBMS has a different dialect for SQL, and MySQL and T-SQL can be very different. If the OP has tagged the wrong RDBMS, they're going to get the "wrong" answers (they'll be right, but likely won't work for them, as the syntax is wrong for what they're using).

Comment: @PratikBhavsar Plus wrong tags won't reach the "right" experts. The question has to be clear before being answered.

Comment: @Larnu As far as the tags are correct does it really matter what links are being used?

Comment: @ModusTollens the tags seem right in this case :)

Comment: The RDBMS im looking at is MS SQL Server management studio 2018.

Comment: @JD_123 As mentioned in initial comments, a lookup table is great in your case.

Comment: @PratikBhavsar it isn't about the links. It is that the OP is running an example for mysql and asking for help with sql server. That is like taking your Ford manual to the Chevy mechanic and asking why the steps to replace the air conditioner don't work. And even with the correct DBMS the code doesn't make logical sense. Case is an expression which returns a scalar value. The OP has a strange hybrid of trying to put some logic in there which doesn't work.

Comment: Agree 100000% that a lookup table is the best way to deal with this.

Comment: @SeanLange He clearly mentioned he is using SQL server management studio but ok. :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert i have put the 291 items in a table with the values i want back,  CASE WHEN Quantity in (12,10,5) THEN Value... what would be the then part ?

Comment: The idea of the lookup table is to provide a way to join your tables. In other words the lookup table would have the values found in OrderDetails and a second column for the value you want returned. There is no need for a case expression at all.

Comment: @PratikBhavsar the OP stated *"i am trying this example on https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_case"*. Emphasis on **trymysql.asp**. This is why Sean, and others of us, here questioning the OP. If the OP wants to try using SQL *Server*, that site is not the right place.

Comment: @JD_123: `ValueIWantBack = (SELECT L.ValueIWantBack FROM LookupTable L WHERE L.Quantity = OrderDetails.Quantity)`, or, per Larnu, use a `[LEFT] JOIN` (I find the subquery syntax clearer if we're only looking up one column, and the optimizer will rewrite it into a join anyway, but your mileage may vary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose a more appropriate solution is to build a list of `VALUES` and lookup:

```
SELECT OrderDetails.OrderID, OrderDetails.Quantity, Lookup.QuantityText
FROM OrderDetails
LEFT JOIN (VALUES
    (12, 1),
    (10, 2),
    ( 5, 3)
) AS Lookup(Quantity, QuantityText) ON OrderDetails.Quantity = Lookup.Quantity
```

Since the list of values is too big you should convert it to an actual table.

Comment: Side note: the `VALUES` clause is limited to 1000 values. For more (and even if you just need to use this more than once) use an actual table. (For 291 cases you may want to use an actual table regardless, as the optimizer tends not to do so well with these "virtual" tables when they get big.)

Comment: im getting a error now;
 Cannot resolve the collation conflict between 2Latinl_General_CT_AS" and "SQL_latinl_General_cp1_ct_as" in the equal to operation

Comment: SELECT OrderDetails.OrderID, OrderDetails.Quantity, Lookup.QuantityText
FROM OrderDetails
LEFT JOIN (VALUES
    (12, 1),
    (10, 2),
    ( 5, 3)
) AS Lookup(Quantity, QuantityText) ON (OrderDetails.orderID+ OrderDetails.Quantity) = Lookup.Quantity

Comment: im trying something like this

Comment: added this and it works collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Oh... I thought Quantity was in integer. If it is varchar then yes, you must resolve collation issue.

Answer (score 3):

Probably easier to show this in an answer now.

As many of us have said, what you want is a lookup table. Let's take an overly simplified `CASE` expression:

```
CASE Quantity WHEN 12 THEN '1'
              WHEN 10 THEN '2'
              WHEN 8 THEN '3'
END AS QuanityText
```

Instead, you would create a table, and insert the values as such:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.QuantityLookup (Quantity int,
                                 QuantityText varchar(5)); --As it had a name like text, I assumed it should be a varchar

INSERT INTO dbo.QuantityLookup
VALUES(12,'1'),(10,'2'),(8,'3');
```

Then you can reference that in your query either by a `JOIN` or subquery:

```
--JOIN (I use a LEFT, as your CASE implies the option of NULL)

SELECT YT.quantity,
       QL.QuantityText 
FROM YourTable YT
     LEFT JOIN dbo.QuantityLookup QL ON YT.Quantity = QL.Quantity;

--subquery

SELECT YT.quantity,
       (SELECT QL.QuantityText FROM dbo.QuantityLookup WHERE QT.Quantity = YT.Quantity) AS QuantityText
FROM YourTable YT;
```

Comment: im getting a error now;
 Cannot resolve the collation conflict between 2Latinl_General_CT_AS" and "SQL_latinl_General_cp1_ct_as" in the equal to operation

Comment: You've used 2 different collations @JD_123 . The error is telling you the problem there.